# deploying imagemagick application using qt

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, qt4, imagemagick

I have create an application that makes use of the ImagemMagick library.

I have succesfully installed the library on my mac and I was able to use it inside my application.

My .pro file Include path and library looks like that:

```
INCLUDEPATH += . /opt/local/include/ImageMagick
LIBS += -L/opt/local/lib -lMagick++
```

I would like to release my application for both Mac and Windows with the library files included.(I dont want the end users to have to install the library themselves)

What are the best practices to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend reading the qt docs about deployment on different platforms:

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/deployment-windows.html

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/deployment-mac.html

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/deployment-x11.html

They basically describe in detail how to deploy dynamically linked libraries with your application. As I know, for Windows it's only distributing the libraries in the same path as the exeecutable, in UNIX / MacOS Environments you'll need to export the proper pathes before starting the applications.

Comment: For mac applications, one creates an App Bundle with the required shared libraries inside, and modifies the rpaths accordingly (macdeployqt can help here, but is not complete). No environment variables required.